# Cocoa bindings call valueForKey: instead of valueForKeyPath:

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSPopUpButton which is bound to a subclassed object, with the following methods overwritten:

```
- (id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath {
    NSLog(@"valueForKeyPath: %@", keyPath);
    if ([keyPath hasSuffix:@"availableVoices.name"]) {
        return self.availableVoiceNames;
    } else {
        return [super valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    }
}

- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSLog(@"valueForKey: %@", key);
    return [super valueForKey:key];
}
```

The bindings are as follows:

- Content -> Object.availableVoices
- Content Values -> Object.availableVoices.name

Instead of `[Object valueForKeyPath:@"availableVoices.name"]` being called, `valueForKey:` is called on each key in the key path. `availableVoices` doesn't have a definition for `name` so it crashes.

Isn't `valueForKey:` supposed to be called after `valueForKeyPath:`, if at all?

Comment: It's a good question, but I do wonder why you don't just directly bind the Content Values to availableVoiceNames.

Comment: @stevesliva If the Content Values key path doesn't start with the key path of the Content binding, the Content Values binding is disregarded.

Comment: Both bindings are combined to one binding.

Comment: @ATLief - Your comment suggests a reason for what you're seeing. If the Content path must be a prefix of the Content Values one then getting the former first and then the latter relative to it makes some sense. Also though Bindings use KVO that doesn't mean it has to use  `valueForKeyPath` - does it state is *will* somewhere?

Comment: @CRD That's a fair point. I'm subclassing **NSSpeechSynthesizer** which subclasses **NSObject**, so it *should* support KVC, but the properties aren't KVO-compliant. I added KVO wrappers to the properties I need to observe for external changes, which is all I need.

Comment: @CRD If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment suggests a reason for what you’re seeing. If the “Content” path must be a prefix of the “Content Values” one then getting the former first and then the latter relative to it makes some sense. Also though Cocoa Bindings uses KVO that doesn’t mean it *has* to use `valueForKeyPath`.